# How to format a number based on locale, while retaining all decimal points?

Tags: java, format

I'm trying to use DecimalFormat to convert the Decimal separator of a double value while retaining all decimals of the original number. DecimalFormatter accepts a pattern in the format: "0.##", for example. Since I have to use numbers with varying decimals, this will not work, however, since the number of decimals always needs to be specified in the pattern.

I am looking for a way to get around this.

I've tried String.format. DecimaFormatter and NumberFormatter

What I would like ideally is something along the lines of:

```
  private static final ThreadLocal< DecimalFormat > formatter = new ThreadLocal< DecimalFormat >() 
  {
    @Override
    protected DecimalFormat initialValue() 
    {
    // n should be any number of decimals without having to specify them.
      return new DecimalFormat("0.0#n");     
    }
  };
```

Some examples:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.0##");
System.out.println(df.format(2.456))
System.out.println(df.format(2.1));
```

Result:

```
2,456 -> Good
2,100 -> Not good
```

I want to set a pattern/regex which will work for doubles of any number of digits after the decimal separator like:

```
2,456 -> Good
2,1 -> Good
3,3453456345234 -> Good
```

Comment: *"...while retaining all the original decimal points of the original number..."* A number can have only at most **one** decimal point (which, depending on culture, might be a `.` or a `,`, etc.). A number may have multiple grouping separators ("thousands" separators in most English-speaking locales, but not all cultures group the same way) (which can also be `.` or `,` or even a space), but only one decimal point. Do you mean grouping separators? Or decimal *places*? Separately: Please show example numbers, incorrectly-formatted ones you're getting, and what they *should * look like instead.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I corrected the original post. I mean the numbers after the separator.

Comment: :-) The English term for that is "decimal places" (but digits after the decimal works too). But again, please provide examples, incorrect output you're getting, and the correct output.

Comment: @AthraelSoju Reread the first Comment by Crowder. You continue to confuse the [concepts and terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal#Decimal_fractions) of the *decimal separator*  that separates the fractional part of the number from the integer part, and *grouping separator* that makes easier reading of the integer part.

Comment: @AthraelSoju I assume you still want to have at least one digit after the decimal point? Else `new DecimalFormat("")` seems to be giving the desired behavior?

Comment: You claim that using format `"0.0##"` on value `2.1` gives output `2,100`, but that is not true. The output is `2,1`, just like you wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numbers in Java (and just numbers, generally) don't have a set number of decimal places. `1.1`, `1.10`, and `1.100` are all **exactly** the same number.

You could find out how many places default formatting would use, e.g.:

```
String str = num.toString();
int decimal = str.indexOf('.');
int places = decimal <= 0 ? 0 : str.length - decimal;
```

...and then specify that many places when using the formatter.

Answer (score 0):

So you have

```
double[] floats = { 3.20, 4.500, 6.34, 1.0000 };
BigDecimal[] fixeds = {
    new BigDecimal("3.20"),
    new BigDecimal("4.500"),
    new BigDecimal("6.34"),
    new BigDecimal("1.0000")
};
```

and want to format them as such, but localized.

The good news is that fixed point numbers with BigDecimal maintain a precision (using the string constructor). The bad news is that floating point is alwaya an approximation, by a sum of (negative) powers of 2. So 3.20 might actually be 3.19999987 or 3.20000043.

They have no fixed decimals. Even without approximation error 3.2 == 3.20 == 3.200.

So convert to BigDecimal (quite ugly), and get rid of the approximation errors: 1000*3.2 != 3200.0.

```
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal("5.1000");
NumberFormat df = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.KOREA);
df.setMinimumFractionDigits(value.getScale()); // 4
String s = df.format(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) has 16 [setter methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#i25) for controlling the output. The pattern string you specify in the constructor is just a convenient way to set most of those values.

To control the locale of the output, you can specify the [`DecimalFormatSymbols`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html), either in the constructor or in a [setter method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setDecimalFormatSymbols-java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols-).

Since you want unlimited decimal places, and it seems you want at least one decimal place, you need to call a setter method, because specifying *unlimited* is not possible with the pattern string.

*Example*

```
private static void test(Locale locale) {
    DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("0.0", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(locale));
    //fmt.setMaximumIntegerDigits(Integer.MAX_VALUE); // already set by pattern
    //fmt.setMinimumIntegerDigits(1);                 // already set by pattern
    //fmt.setMinimumFractionDigits(1);                // already set by pattern
    fmt.setMaximumFractionDigits(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    //fmt.setGroupingUsed(false);                     // already set by pattern

    System.out.println(locale.toLanguageTag() + " (" + locale.getDisplayLanguage(Locale.US) +
                                               " - " + locale.getDisplayCountry(Locale.US) + ")");
    System.out.println("  " + fmt.format(123456789));
    System.out.println("  " + fmt.format(2.456));
    System.out.println("  " + fmt.format(2.1));
    System.out.println("  " + fmt.format(3.3453456345234));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    test(Locale.US);
    test(Locale.GERMANY);
    test(Locale.forLanguageTag("ar-EG"));
}
```

*Output (OpenJDK 11.0.1)*

```
en-US (English - United States)
  123456789.0
  2.456
  2.1
  3.3453456345234
de-DE (German - Germany)
  123456789,0
  2,456
  2,1
  3,3453456345234
ar-EG (Arabic - Egypt)
  ١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩٫٠
  ٢٫٤٥٦
  ٢٫١
  ٣٫٣٤٥٣٤٥٦٣٤٥٢٣٤
```